# No response from server when accessing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string

I am new here so I am not sure if I am asking this in the right way. Tell me if you need more information on anything.

I just started working on an MVC project. I am still new to it and having some connection problems. Problem is as following:

I made an internet application (with the build in login system).
When running the website in localhost I have no problems connecting to my database which is running at the hosting provider.

After publishing i stumble on a problem. I can view the website etc. but when I enter a page which is using the database I get a time-out with the following error message:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

I did some research, but didn't really find anything useful.

The Connectionstring must be right since I can access the database while running in localhost.

Any ideas?

I disabled customerrors so it will show the full errormessage.
If you want to see the full errormessage the site is running at http://sports-records.nl/
I just wanted to start with getting the login system/ database connection to work before continuing with anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [help link](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is on your webpage.

Comment: I did read the pages on deployment, still haven't found what i am looking for. Is it possible that this has something to do with the hosting provider?

Comment: The problem is solved... the connection string i used was for external connections.